# Jquery Flot is not displaying Yaxis when there is only 1 point

Tags: jquery, flot

I have a graphic with just 1 point. The Y axis is a date axis. It works fine, but when the graphic have just one point the Y axis is not displaying the date value on the Y axis.

Is there a way to force the Y axis to being displayed? (already tryed with yaxis: { show: true })

Code Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pFB8s/

`var options = {
                xaxis: {
                            show: true, 
                            mode: 'time', 
                            minTickSize: [1, 'day'], 
                            timeformat: '%d %b %y'
                }, 
                yaxis: { 
                            minTickSize: 0.5 
                }, 
                series: { 
                            lines: { show: true }, 
                            points: { show: true } 
                }
};`

$.plot($('#chartDiv'), [[[1372339686000, 78.000]]], options);

Comment: Please provide code or a jsFiddle that replicates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem... Seems that when there is only one point the option minTickSize for that axis is bothering.